# Add section with animation in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

I am working in iPhone application, Using UITableView to develop my application. i have 3 section and each section have 1 row, when the user press UIButton in Section1 to call B1 method for add one more section and row in this tableview. its working fine.

i have tried to add animation (for add one more section and row).

```
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
```

But animate all rows and sections, but i want to add animation in add section and row at the time.
How to handle this please help me?

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     ExpandActive = NO;
    self.title=@"Expand Tables";
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(ExpandActive == YES)
    {
        return 4; 
    }
    else
    {
         return 3;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{




    if(ExpandActive == YES)
    {
        if(section == 0)
        {
            return @"Header1";
        }
        else  if(section == 1)
        {
             return @"Header1";
        }
        else if(section == 2)
        {
             return @"Header1";    
        }
        else if(section == 3)
        {
             return @"Header1";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if(section == 0)
        {
             return @"Header1";
        }
        else  if(section == 1)
        {
             return @"Header1";
        }
        else if(section == 2)
        {
             return @"Header1";
        }
    }   
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    if(ExpandActive == YES)
    {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(B1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn];

            UIButton *btn1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn1 setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn1.frame = CGRectMake(180, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(B2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn1];
            cell.backgroundView = bg;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:bg];
        }
        else if(indexPath.section == 1) 
        {   
            text = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 50)];
            text.text=@"sdadd";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:text];
        }
        else if(indexPath.section == 2) 
        {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(B5) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn];

            UIButton *btn1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn1 setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn1.frame = CGRectMake(180, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(B6) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn1];
            cell.backgroundView = bg;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:bg];
        }
        else if(indexPath.section == 3) 
        {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(B5) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn];

            UIButton *btn1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn1 setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn1.frame = CGRectMake(180, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(B6) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn1];
            cell.backgroundView = bg;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:bg];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(B1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn];

            UIButton *btn1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn1 setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn1.frame = CGRectMake(180, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(B2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn1];
            cell.backgroundView = bg;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:bg];
        }
        else if(indexPath.section == 1) 
        {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(B3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn];

            UIButton *btn1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn1 setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn1.frame = CGRectMake(180, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(B4) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn1];
            cell.backgroundView = bg;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:bg]; 
        }
        else if(indexPath.section == 2) 
        {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIButton *btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(B5) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn];

            UIButton *btn1 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [btn1 setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btn1.frame = CGRectMake(180, 5, 120, 40);
            [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(B6) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bg addSubview:btn1];
            cell.backgroundView = bg;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:bg];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)B1
{

    NSLog(@"B1");
    ExpandActive = YES;
    [text removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(void)B2
{
    NSLog(@"B2");
    ExpandActive = NO;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [text removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to add the new section as section 1. Update your two button methods like this:

```
-(void)B1 {
    NSLog(@"B1");
    ExpandActive = YES;

    [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

-(void)B2 {
    NSLog(@"B2");
    ExpandActive = NO;

    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Feel free to use a different animation.

BTW - you have a lot of duplicate code. You need to eliminate all of the duplicate code.

Here's an example:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger effectiveSection = section;
    if (ExpandActive && effectiveSection > 1) {
        effectiveSection++;
    }

    switch (effectiveSection) {
        case 0:
            return @"Fixed Section 1";
        case 1:
            return @"Optional Section";
        case 2:
            return @"Fixed Section 2";
        case 3:
            return @"Fixed Section 3";
    }

    return nil; // this shouldn't be reached but makes the compiler happy
}
```

Another thing, don't implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method if you have a fixed height. It's very inefficient. Instead, set the `rowHeight` property on the table view. A good place for this is in `viewDidLoad`. Just set it once and you are done.

One more - there is no need to set `userInteractionEnabled` on a table cell or view. It is enabled by default. It's disabled for things like `UILabel` and `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `– insertSections:withRowAnimation:` method of UITableView. You must also handle number of sections returned in `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method.