# iOS - perform animation on tableView reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have to perform some animation effect on `tableView` - section and rows while displaying for the first time. The animation behaviour is illustrated below

[image]

On taking a deeper look, the `sectionView` slides in from left to right (dark grey). On completion of `sectionView` animation, the rows starts to animate (light grey). Basically the rows slides down from the top item, one after the other. Approximately, on 50% completion of row one animation, row two starts to appear. How would I achieve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656580/add-section-with-animation-in-uitableview?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410482/table-view-cell-load-animation-one-after-another

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35600493/500625 addressed my question - did some tweak peaks in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Good question. It would be tricky.

I guess you'd have to create custom table view cells (or content views that go in table view cells) that support animating into place. I'd say you'd create the view, and then apply a mask animation that would show it from left to right or top to bottom.

If you want your top-to-bottom animation to make your cells get taller as well as getting more opaque, it would be move complicated still.